# Mixing up languages and technologies: Is it a good idea?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, architecture

Please have a look at the following design. It is a Block diagram, which is created to display COMPONENTS

[image]

Please note this is a diagram for a desktop application. What you see here are components, and not classes. Following is the description

```
C++/CLI code - The main GUI and the connector for all other services
OpenCV C++ Code - set of Opencv classes for image and video processing
C++ SMS Code - set of SMS classes written in C++

C# wrapper DLL - The dll to access the driver
C# Driver DLL - The driver of the device, written in C#
Speech recognition C# dll - set of speech recognition classes

Google Map DLL/JAR - Google map classes written in either C# or Java

Device - The device I need to access
```

Now, my question.

As you can see, this is a collection of technologies and languages. For me, it seems pretty easy to write all the Speech code in c# rather than moving them to C++/CLI (Other C# dlls are mandatory to be C#). But, I feel like too much dlls integrating with other C++ code. 
I can't create the GUI in C# or Java. I must implement Opencv (the main thing) and the easiest way is C++.

So, is it OK/good to mix up languages and technologies like this, just like a mixture??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution provides you with the expectations and performance that you want and is easy enough to maintain, then I don't see a problem with it. If you look at Linux, it's built on lots of small programs often linked together, so using C++ with perl, php, ruby, C code etc is not unusual.

OSX, for example requires writing UI (cocoa) code in Objective-C, while drivers use C++ and kernel extensions in C.

Comment: wow! I am glad to know! Anyway, I will wait for some more ideas from other members as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd drop the JAR and use the .Net classes there. No benefit in adding Java.

I'd move the whole set of C# blocks (Speech, map, driver, wrapper) to their own process, and define an IPC protocol (probably TCP/IP to localhost) to communicate with the C++ part. That I'd keep in native C++. As a result, you have one pure C++ process and one pure C# process.

As part of the IPC protocol design, I'd hide the details of the SMS and Speech blocks. You should be able to replace the implementation without the other side noticing.

Comment: IPC? hmm, Then this becomes a web based project, isn't it?

Comment: No, ipc is inter process communication (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

@MSalters You have to take latencies into account. If they are not a problem, I'd go for the seperate process solution. Helps to define clean interfaces.